# Implement my own hash algorithm for a hash function in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, hash, hash-function

I am modeling the user sign-in and account creation of a social network and have to create a hash function (not using hashlib) using my own hashing algorithm. The point of it is to take a password and hash it so that it becomes a random string of letters and numbers. The hashed password should also change dramatically when only one letter of the password is changed. For example, if "heyguys" goes to 7h8362, "hayguys" would go to something totally different like "bbb362". A small change in input string should result in a large change in output string. The reason I am doing this is because I am storing user data in a dictionary and it is dangerous to store a password in plaintext.

How would I go about doing this? I am a beginner and know hashlib but other than that, I cannot seem to figure out where to even begin.

Comment: If you're a beginner, you shouldn't be doing this. You should be using a standardized hashing algorithm such as SHA-256 and, if in any way possible, using someone else's implementation of it, not your own. You also need to use a random per-user salt hashed with the password in order to make rainbow table attacks infeasible.

Comment: Have you tried looking at standard approaches? There are way too many options, a quick google for "python crypto hash example" will give you most of the information you need.

Comment: Since youre a beginner, simply use the standard hashes instead of a self-designed one. Designing an own hash-algorithm requires quite a lot of mathematical skills and should be left to professionals.

Comment: @DarkFalcon: Heck no, SHA-256 isn't going to cut it. You want an algorithm designed for password hashing, like [bcrypt or scrypt](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846).

Comment: please follow user2357112's suggestions! just hashing is bad for several reasons; e.g. it would reveal if 2 users use the same password. and brute-forcing would be way too easy. consider using (in that order): scrypt, bcrypt, PBKDF2.

Comment: If you want more constructive answers, consider explaining why you want to develop your own algorithm, rather than use the standard hashes. Do you think a proprietary algorithm would be safer or do you want to learn how these things are done or is it something else?

Comment: I'm doing this for an assignment in an introductory computing course. We were told that while in practice, using standard libraries is strongly recommended, it trivializes the project. They want us to use one that we come up with for full credit.

Comment: "Doing that almost trivializes that project. While using standard libraries rather than writing your own is strongly advisable in practice, for the purposes of this project, we would like you to use one that you come up with for full credit. If nothing else, you will appreciate the challenges associated with it. You are welcome to do research online, read and understand code written by others, and borrow ideas (with proper citation). If you still want to go ahead and use hashlib, you can but then be prepared to lose some credit"

Answer (score 4):

As others have said here, this is an advanced topic, and you shouldn't try to make a feasible Hash function unless you know what you're doing.

However, if you want to understand the basics of hashing, here are some things to think about.

1. Equivalent output: In every Hash function, you should be able to get the same output for every input that is identical to each other, such that, `hash(8) = 'y758tff'` should be `'y758tff'` every time `hash(8)` is called.
2. Avoiding Collisions: Good Hashing functions give unique outputs for as many inputs as possible. Meaning, `Hash(n)` and `Hash(x)`, should not give the same Hash output, and if it has to happen, it should be very rare.
3. Irreversibility: A good hash function, will be near impossible to reverse back to its key. Meaning, for every `Hash(n) = N`, there should be no function so that `function(N) = n`. As an example, if you had a hash function that simply reverses the input, it would be very easy to make a function that reverses that Hash output.
4. Identical lengths of keys: Regardless of the length of an input for a good hash function, the output must be the same length of all inputs. Such that, `Hash('a') = '46fhur78'`, and `Hash('Tomatoes') = 'yfih78rr'`, both length of 8.